# Embedding cordova application on Android native application

Tags: android, cordova, cordovawebview

What I'm trying to do is embed a cordova application into a native android application.

It seems to me that the documentation is out of date or not clear about the steps that needs to be done.

Documentation:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html

I am at the point that I can't create the `.jar` file for the following reasons.

1. I don't have a `/framework` directory in my root project directory or in `platforms/android`
2. Cordova seems to be using `gradle` instead of `ant` for building the android project. I can't find a `build.xml` anywhere in the android project.

My Cordova version: 8.0.0

As as followup question, I expect this `.jar` file will also contain the plugins that the cordova project depends on, correct?

Comment: the docs are totally out of date, you have to use gradle now and add the dependency as `implementation 'org.apache.cordova:framework:7.1.1'`. It won't include plugins because plugins were extracted from Cordova core, you should use plugman to install them, but last time I tried it wasn't working on non Cordova projects